# Elegant way to check if a list contains an object where one property is the same, and replace only if the date of another property is later

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, comparison

I have a class as follows :

```
Object1{
   int id;
   DateTime time;
}
```

I have a list of `Object1`. I want to cycle through another list of `Object1`, search for an `Object1` with the same ID and replace it in the first list if the time value is later than the time value in the list. If the item is not in the first list, then add it.

I'm sure there is an elegant way to do this, perhaps using linq? :

```
List<Object1> listOfNewestItems = new List<Object1>();
List<Object1> listToCycleThrough = MethodToReturnList();
foreach(Object1 object in listToCycleThrough){
   if(listOfNewestItems.Contains(//object1 with same id as object))
   {
      //check date, replace if time property is > existing time property 
   } else {
      listOfNewestItems.Add(object)
}
```

Obviously this is very messy (and that's without even doing the check of properties which is messier again...), is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Could there be more than 1 item with the same ID in the new list?

Comment: in ListToCycleThrough there could be, in ListOfNewestItems, there shouldnt be (I'm trying to only put in this the newest unique id values)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var finalList = list1.Concat(list2)
                     .GroupBy(x => x.id)
                     .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y=>y.time).First())
                     .ToList();
```

---

here is the full code to test

```
public class Object1
{
    public int id;
    public DateTime time;
}

List<Object1> list1 = new List<Object1>() 
{
    new Object1(){id=1,time=new DateTime(1991,1,1)},
    new Object1(){id=2,time=new DateTime(1992,1,1)}
};

List<Object1> list2 = new List<Object1>() 
{
    new Object1(){id=1,time=new DateTime(2001,1,1)},
    new Object1(){id=3,time=new DateTime(1993,1,1)}
};
```

and OUTPUT:

```
1 01.01.2001 
2 01.01.1992 
3 01.01.1993
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to check:

```
foreach(var object in listToCycleThrough)
{
    var currentObject = listOfNewestItems
                              .SingleOrDefault(obj => obj.Id == object.Id);

    if(currentObject != null)
    {
        if (currentObject.Time < object.Time) 
                  currentObject.Time = object.Time
    } 

    else 
        listOfNewestItems.Add(object)
}
```

But if you have large data, would be suggested to use `Dictionary` in newest list, time to look up will be O(1) instead of O(n)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ. [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) to get the set difference(the newest), and `join` to find the newer objects.

```
var listOfNewestIDs = listOfNewestItems.Select(o => o.id);
var listToCycleIDs = listToCycleThrough.Select(o => o.id);
var newestIDs = listOfNewestIDs.Except(listToCycleIDs);
var newestObjects = from obj in listOfNewestItems
                    join objID in newestIDs on obj.id equals objID
                    select obj;
var updateObjects = from newObj in listOfNewestItems
                    join oldObj in listToCycleThrough on newObj.id equals oldObj.id
                    where newObj.time > oldObj.time
                    select new { oldObj, newObj };

foreach (var updObject in updateObjects)
    updObject.oldObj.time = updObject.newObj.time;
listToCycleThrough.AddRange(newestObjects);
```

Note that you need to add `using System.Linq;`.

Here's a demo: http://ideone.com/2ASli

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a `Dictionary` to lookup the index for an `Id` and use that

```
var newItems = new List<Object1> { ...
IList<Object1> itemsToUpdate = ... 

var lookup = itemsToUpdate.
        Select((i, o) => new { Key = o.id, Value = i }).
        ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value);

foreach (var newItem in newitems)
{
    if (lookup.ContainsKey(newitem.ID))
    {
        var i = lookup[newItem.Id];
        if (newItem.time > itemsToUpdate[i].time)
        {
            itemsToUpdate[i] = newItem;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        itemsToUpdate.Add(newItem)
    }
}
```

That way, you wouldn't need to reenumerate the list for each new item, you'd benefit for the hash lookup performance.

---

This should work however many times an `Id` is repeated in the list of new items.